# Alternative for AllowTransparency

Tags: wpf, winforms, transparency

Is there any other way I can get the transaprency feature for the WPF window, other than setting the AllowTransparency property to true? I am placing a WinForm in my application, and setting this property to true affects loading content into the WinForm. So, any workarounds for AllowTransparency property? Thanks!

Comment: How does it affect loading content into the WinForms control? Have you set the `TransparencyKey` `Color` of the control?

Comment: Sorry, content is loading, but not shown in Winform.

Comment: Please take a look at the [`Form.TransparencyKey` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey.aspx) page on MSDN to see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but sorry, it doesn't meet my requirements. I want the WPF window to be transparent without using the AllowTransparency property